# WPF Store Additional Tag-like information?

Tags: wpf

I am adding TabItems to my TabControl through code:

```
TabItem tab = new TabItem();
tab.Tag = type;
tab.Name = name;
tabControl.Items.Add(tab);
```

As you can see, I am using the `Tag` property to store an additional piece of meta information. However, I need to store some additional information for one reason or another. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You can store object array within Tag as well. However, in case you want to extend it you can also declare some attached property to hold your data.

Comment: You can extend TabItem if you want, and have whatever you need there I guess ...

Comment: You can set Tag like this as well - `tab.Tag = new object[] {type, property1, property2}` Or create [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753957(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How do I then retrieve the data? `tab.Tag[0].ToString()` isn't working.

Comment: `var tagInformation = tab.Tag as object[]; string type = tagInformation[0].ToString();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store information in Tag as an **`object[]`** or can create [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753957(v=vs.110).aspx) to store distinct information in case required.

To store the information as object[ ]:

```
tab.Tag = new object[] {type, property1, property2};
```

and to retrieve it back:

```
var tagInformation = tab.Tag as object[];
string type = tagInformation[0].ToString();
```